# How to remove PR review comment?

Tags: github

I submited feedback suggesting changes for pull request and can't remove it.

There were two same blocks with my comment on PR timeline. I removed a second one, but can't do so for the first block, there is no such option, only edit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Pull Request Reviews API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/reviews) only includes:

> ### [Delete a review comment for a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/comments#delete-a-review-comment-for-a-pull-request)
>
> (using GitHub CLI [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api))
>
> ```bash
> gh api \
>  --method DELETE \
>  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
>  /repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/comments/COMMENT_ID
> ```

Try and [list all review comments](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/comments#list-review-comments-in-a-repository) to check the right ID for your review comment, and try to delete it that way.

---

As noted by [fregante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288906/fregante) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73427238/how-to-remove-pr-review-comment/73429150#comment137323180_73429150), it is clear that "[submitted reviews cannot be deleted](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/reviews?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-a-pending-review-for-a-pull-request)".

But this question is about deleting review *comments*, not the review itself.

Comment: That only deletes the single comments, not the main review, which is what the question is about. The linked documentation is clear that ["submitted reviews cannot be deleted,"](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/reviews?apiVersion=2022-11-28#delete-a-pending-review-for-a-pull-request) which is why the UI on GitHub.com does not show a "Delete review" action

Comment: @fregante Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.